# Is there a way to bump the non-right most part of the version in RPM?

Tags: rpm, rpm-spec

With `rpmdev-bumpspec` I can do

> ```
> -r, --rightmost
>       bump trailing .<DIGIT> component if found, append .1 if not; no-op if -s is specified
>
> -s STRING, --string=STRING
>       bump trailing .STRING<DIGIT> component if found, append .STRING1 if not; trumps -r
> ```

That's great for changing the last version in semver `1.2.3` because you can set your spec like,

```
Version:        1.2
Release:        2%{?dist}
```

And then run `rpmdev-bumpspec -r` and you'll have `1.2.3`, but what if you want to bump the `1.2` or hard set the version to something that follows [`semver`](https://semver.org/) is there a tool to do this? Or, do I have to roll my own?

Comment: Edit the .spec file?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No (contribution to rpmdev-bumpspec are welcome: https://pagure.io/rpmdevtools and https://pagure.io/rpmdevtools/blob/master/f/rpmdev-bumpspec).

But you can:

```
rpmspec -q --qf "%{version}\n" your.spec |head -n1
```

pass it to `awk` or `sed` and then:

```
rpmdev-bumpspec --new=NEWVALUE your.spec
```